# Not sure which way of combining my loop results I should be using

Tags: r, loops, soundcloud

To make a long story short I'm trying to gather information on 6500 user, so I wrote a loop. Below you can find an example of 10 artists. In this loop I'm trying to use a call to gather information on all tracks of a user.

```
test <- fromJSON(getURL('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/52880864/tracks?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d&limit=200&offset=1&linked_partitioning=1'))
```

This short example shows a dataframe with all the tracks uploaded by a user. When I use my loop I'd like to add all the dataframes together so that I can process them with tapply. This way I can for instance see how what the sum of all track likes are. However, two things are going wrong. First, when I run the loop, each users only shows one uploaded track. Second, I think I'm not combining the dataframes properly. Could somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
id <- c(20376298, 63320169, 3806325, 12231483, 18838035, 117385796, 52880864, 32704993, 63975320, 95667573)

Partition1 <- paste0("'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/", id, "/tracks?client_id=0ab2657a7e5b63b6dbc778e13c834e3d&limit=200&offset=1&linked_partitioning=1'")

results <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(Partition1)) 
for (i in seq_along(Partition1)){
message(paste0('Query #',i))
tryCatch({
result_i <- fromJSON((getURL(str_replace_all(Partition1[i],"'","")))) 
clean_i <- function(x)ifelse(is.null(x),NA,ifelse(length(x)==0,NA,x))
results[[i]] <- plyr::llply(result_i, clean_i) %>% as_data_frame
if( i == 4 ) {
  stop('stop')
}
}, error = function(e){
beepr::beep(1)
}
)
Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Comment: `clean_i <- function(x)ifelse(is.null(x),NA,ifelse(length(x)==0,NA,x))`  should be declared out of the loop. But I'm not sure what is it supposed to do, on which column is it supposed to be applied. What are you trying to sum from _result_i_ ? Also, your example lacks dependencies (`dplyr`, `RCurl`, etc.)

Comment: You're absolutely right. The packages I've used here are 'RCurl', 'plyr', 'jsonlite' and 'dplyr'. I applied that clean function so that all null values are changed to NA. Null values were keeping me from creating a data frame, that is why I left it in the loop. I'm trying to sum the lists from all the users that are in result_i.